# can i use the facebook data for my data mining project

Tags: facebook, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

First i will tell what i want to achieve in my data mining  project and then i will ask questions.

I am thinking of using the facebook to find particular user from particular location and from particular community. Then based upon their daily wall posting and likes , dislikes i want to generate a report on what user of particular community are doing or interested in.

Is that legal , i mean can i use my crawler to grab those users public data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Facebook **Terms of Service**.

That is what they are for, they tell you what you are allowed to do on their site and what not.

Most likely you are not allowed to access the web site with spiders, and the Facebook API will restrict your data gathering capabilities with rate control etc. except for users that are running your application (or you pay for the data...)